# make_tuple passes a type T as T&&, when expecting T as a templated argument

Tags: c++, tuples, point-cloud-library

I am trying to make a tuple of type tuple, pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandler > but when I pass arguments of the corresponding type into std::make_tuple, it says that the argument passed as pcl::PointCloud is actually pcl::PointCloud&&, which if I am correct is an rvalue reference.  I do not understand how the type pcl::PointCloud becomes an rvalue reference.  Here is the code:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> cloud;
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::ConstPtr constCloud(&cloud);
pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZRGB>(file.getPCDFilePath().string(), cloud);
pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<pcl::PointXYZRGB> rgbHandler(constCloud);
associatedClouds.insert(std::make_tuple<std::string, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>, pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<pcl::PointXYZRGB> >(file.getPCDFileName(), cloud, rgbHandler));
visualizedFiles.push_back(cloud);
```

The error I get is:

```
/Users/wfehrnstrom/CmakeTest/map.cpp:53:29: error: no matching function for call to 'make_tuple'
    associatedClouds.insert(std::make_tuple<std::string, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>, pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<pcl::PointXYZRGB> >(file.getPCDFileName(), cloud, rgbHandler));
                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/tuple:868:1: note: candidate function [with _Tp = <std::__1::basic_string<char>, pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>, pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandlerRGBField<pcl::PointXYZRGB>>] not viable: no known conversion from 'pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>' to 'pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB> &&' for 2nd argument
make_tuple(_Tp&&... __t)
```

I'm pretty lost.  Thank you.

Comment: Remove `<>` from `make_tuple`, just `std::make_tuple(file.getPCDFileName(), cloud, rgbHandler);` let template argument deduction do its job.

Comment: Please format your question. It looks like a dog ate half of it. Embedded code snippets go between backticks lile this: `\`foo<int>\``.

Answer (score 2):

Never Use `make_tuple` with explicit template arguments.

That's the quote i remember from Microsoft STL maintainer, the reason is that `make_tuple` is smart enough to strip extra references and by explicitly stating the template arguments you are defeating it's purpose.

The other thing is that `file.getPCDFileName()` is an `Rvalue Reference`,
Temporaries returned from functions are rvalue. you can use a local variable `auto filename = file.getPCDFileName()` and then `make_tuple(file_name, ...`.